# How to speed up the force layout animation in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3.js for rendering about 500 nodes and links among them. It usually needs 10 seconds for the layout to settle down (the iteration to converge).

How do I speed up the whole process,say, the nodes are moving 2x faster during animation. then the time will be 50% (The CPU time that used for the iteration should be much less than 10 seconds, but how can I reduce the animation time).

I have tried:

1. manually manage the tick() in a for loop with certain times, say, 100 times, it is faster, but the animation will be hidden from the user, which is a big loss.
2. Increasing the link strength will be helpful, nodes will move much faster during animation. But the layout is very sensitive, any small drag might cause many nodes move.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: If you skip tick events for drawing, use a transition instead of just setting the node positions. This way the layout will still seem fluid.

Answer (score 21):

Check out [**this thread**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1519) which has a lot of good info relating to this topic.

One suggestion from that thread that you might try to implement is to call `force.tick()` several times within a single `requestAnimationFrame` callback, then update the node and link positions, and then loop until `force.alpha` reaches 0 (or whatever you want your alpha threshold to be). Try something like this:

```
var ticksPerRender = 3;

requestAnimationFrame(function render() {

  for (var i = 0; i < ticksPerRender; i++) {
    force.tick();
  }

  // UPDATE NODE AND LINK POSITIONS HERE

  if (force.alpha() > 0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
});
```

That would render once for every 3 ticks, or 3x speed. Adjust the `ticksPerRender` value as needed.

[**HERE**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wyBZbR6f4MMV5BG05u48?p=preview) is a simple demo. In this case, I've used the `force.on('start', callback)` to call the rendering logic described above. This means it will automatically be called again when beginning a drag interaction.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion, I'm currently looking at a way to measure browser performance, and combined with modifying the load on the rendering side of the browser this is a great way to tweak settings.

Comment: @jshanley I don't know if this is still valid. I'm changing the tick count on your plunkr but I don't see a difference.

Comment: @echonax and others, you should see a difference if you crank the ticksPerRender value up (I put it at 30 and the graph cools almost instantly)

Answer (score 5):

Injecting a call / calls within ticked event handler can be better, the requestAnimationFrame method would cause a weird bug on MacBook with touch pad environment.

```
function ticked() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    force.tick();
  }

  link.attr('x1', (d) => d.source.x)
      .attr('y1', (d) => d.source.y)
      .attr('x2', (d) => d.target.x)
      .attr('y2', (d) => d.target.y);

  node.attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two performant alternatives to D3's built-in force algorithm:

- https://github.com/twosixlabs/d3-force-reuse
- https://github.com/twosixlabs/d3-force-sampled