# Optimize Voronoi + force directed layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, voronoi

So basically I have a force directed graph where the nodes are the center points of the voronoi layout.

It updates the voronoi in the tick function whenever any of the nodes are dragged. Obviously this is computationally pretty expensive, so I was wondering if anyone out there had any opinions on optimizing the code to cut off any unnecessary code.

Specifically I was thinking about these code segments.

```
force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

            if(settled === 1) {
                preset = "[";
                gens = "["
                node.attr("cx", function(d) {
                    preset = preset + "[" + d.x + "," + d.y + "],";
                    gens = gens + d.g + ",";
                    return d.x;
                });
                preset = preset.substring(0, preset.length - 1) + "]";
                gens = gens.substring(0, gens.length - 1) + "]";

                path = path.data(d3.geom.voronoi(eval(preset)), polygon);

                path.exit().remove();

                path.enter().append("path")
                    .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "q" + (i % 9) + "-9"; })
                    .attr("d", polygon)
                    .style("fill",function(d,i){
                        var point = d.point;
                        var gens;
                        node.attr("cx", function(d) {
                            if(d.x === point[0] && d.y === point[1]) gens = d.g;
                            return d.x; }
                        );
                        return gens >= 0 ? colsa[gens] :  "none";
                    })
                    .style("fill-opacity",0.75);

                path.order();
            }
        });

        force.on("end", function() {
            if(settled === 0) {
                preset = "[";
                gens = "["
                node.attr("cx", function(d) {
                    preset = preset + "[" + d.x + "," + d.y + "],";
                    gens = gens + d.g + ",";
                    return d.x;
                });
                preset = preset.substring(0, preset.length - 1) + "]";
                gens = gens.substring(0, gens.length - 1) + "]";

                path = svg.select("#voro").selectAll("path")
                    .data(d3.geom.voronoi(eval(preset)))
                    .enter().append("svg:path")
                    .attr("class", function(d, i) { return i ? "q" + (i % 9) + "-9" : null; })
                    .attr("d", polygon)
                    .style("fill",function(d,i){
                        var point = d.point;
                        var gens;
                        node.attr("cx", function(d) {
                            if(d.x === point[0] && d.y === point[1]) gens = d.g;
                            return d.x; }
                        );
                        return gens >= 0 ? colsa[gens] :  "none";
                    })
                    .style("fill-opacity",0.75);
                settled = settled + 1;
            }
        });
```

I recodnize that right now it is implemented in a really hackish way which is why I was hoping there might be something better. Specifically here:

```
node.attr("cx", function(d) {
                    preset = preset + "[" + d.x + "," + d.y + "],";
                    gens = gens + d.g + ",";
                    return d.x;
                });
```

and here:

```
node.attr("cx", function(d) {
                            if(d.x === point[0] && d.y === point[1]) gens = d.g;
                            return d.x; }
                        );
```

I am taking advantage of the fact that D3 loops through all of the node/link elements and gives me access to there attributes of the data object, where as looking at node directly I only have access to the SVG element.

I thought maybe it would be possible to add the voronoi polygons one at a time within the process of adding the nodes.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4pmLm2gL/

Comment: See the information in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188266/how-to-speed-up-the-force-layout-animation-in-d3-js).

Comment: Thanks that worked for speeding things up. Any thoughts on better implementations though?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution/improvement?