# Is it possible to skip the inital transitions in D3 force layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have used the D3 example force layout data from here : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

And transferred it to this example : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804919

Outcome JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/q2shr6ne/6/

This works well, but I need this to be able to work with thousands of nodes. I have tested it with around 3000 and it takes a good few minutes to settle. Example here : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/q2shr6ne/7/

I have found this example as well as more :

[How to speed up the force layout animation in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188266/how-to-speed-up-the-force-layout-animation-in-d3-js)

But I need to have their end positions as I dont want any transition at the start. Is this possible ?

Code for how they get positioned :

```
function tick(e) {

  circle
      .each(gravity(0.2*e.alpha))
      .each(collide(.5))
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// Move nodes toward cluster focus.
function gravity(alpha) {
  return function(d) { 
    d.y += (d.cy - d.y) * alpha;
    d.x += (d.cx - d.x) * alpha;
  };
}

// Resolve collisions between nodes.
function collide(alpha) {
  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(data.nodes);
  return function(d) {
 // console.log(d.radius)
    var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
        nx1 = d.x - r,
        nx2 = d.x + r,
        ny1 = d.y - r,
        ny2 = d.y + r;
    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
            y = d.y - quad.point.y,
            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
            r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.color !== quad.point.color) * padding;
        if (l < r) {
          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          quad.point.x += x;
          quad.point.y += y;
        }
      }
      return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    });
  };
}
```

I have found this example : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139

But having a difficult time implementing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works fine for me :

```
  setTimeout(function() {

      force.start();
      for (var i = n * n; i > 0; --i) force.tick();
      force.stop();
  }, 10);
```

and comment the `start()` after the `force` definition

See : https://jsfiddle.net/q2shr6ne/8/

Comment: I was complicating things for myself by thinking force.tick was calling a default tick function rather than remembering i set it on .on('tick',tick). Thanks for pointing that one out :)