# D3 force directed graph performance issue

Tags: javascript, d3-force-directed

I am using  3d-force-graph(1.43.9).
I am loading 1000 nodes and 1000 links in D3 graph with images.
When it's loading it takes more CPU allocation.So it's crashes my browser.
How to reduce CPU allocation and speed up the graph performance.
please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to speed up the force layout animation in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188266/how-to-speed-up-the-force-layout-animation-in-d3-js)

Comment: Is there anyway to improve the performance of the graph without changing animation?